# requestAnimationFrame() does not seem to always repaint my newly applied css transforms

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, rendering

If anybody could help me, I would greatly appreciate it. I am using `requestAnimationFrame()` to apply a vertical translate on an element with CSS, and I want the vertical translate distance to relate to the vertical scroll position. My issue is that it seems like some frames either do not call my function or do not repaint with the updated CSS when using the scroll wheel (testing with Chrome and Firefox, both up-to-date).

This is a trimmed down version (optimizations removed) to show the root of what I'm trying to do:

```
let sticky = document.getElementById('top');

function changePos() {
    let position = window.scrollY;
    sticky.style.transform = `translateY(${position}px)`;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(changePos);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(changePos);
```

You can see a full working demo on [this upload](http://test.talonz.com/rafConfusion.html). For some reason clicking and dragging the scrollbar doesn't miss any frames, but using the mouse wheel does. You may have to throttle CPU using dev tools to see the missed frames, or use an older computer or phone.

Thanks so much.

Comment: "this codepen" shows nothing, unless you login ... no thanks ... do better browsers also behave the way you describe?

Comment: @JaromandaX - Thanks. Reuploaded to my own server and changed the link to that. You can see the behavior on Chrome, Firefox, and Chrome for Mobile. You may have to throttle your CPU with dev tools or use an older computer/device.